# How to open and close a search bar in reacatjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, modal-dialog

I need to open a very simple search bar in reactjs, and there is no closing button because I want to click on the same button to close it.

Here is some code I tried out but didn't work.

```
  const [searchIsOpen, setSearchIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const search = () => {
    if (searchIsOpen) {
      setSearchIsOpen(true);
    } else {
      setSearchIsOpen(false);
    }
  };

<button onClick={search}
        className="absolute md:left-8 left-3 lg:left-2 top-6 md:top-8 cursor-pointer"> 
 </button>
```

## And this element should open.

```
    <div>
  <input type="text" name="" id="" />
  </div>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use conditional rendering.

```
const [searchIsOpen, setSearchIsOpen] = useState(false);
const search = () => {
  setSearchIsOpen(!searchIsOpen);
};





<button onClick={search} className="absolute md:left-8 left-3 lg:left-2 top-6 md:top-8 cursor-pointer"></button>
{
  searchIsOpen && <div>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" />
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  { searchIsOpen && <input type="text" name="" id="" /> }
</div>
```